# Find optimal fishing plan

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, operations-research

> A population of $N$ fish in a certain lake grow at rate $$N'(t) = aN(t) - bN^2(t)$$
>   if undisturbed by people. Fish can be withdrawn from the lake and consumed at
>   rate $c(t)$, yielding utility $w(c(t))$ to the consuming community and reducing the
>   fish growth rate accordingly: $$N'(t) = aN(t) - bN^2(t) - c(t)$$
>
> Assume future utilities to the community are discounted at constant rate $r$.
>   Characterize a fishing (consumption) plan to maximize the present value of the
>   discounted stream of utilities. Assume that $N(0) = \frac{a}{b}$, and that $u' > 0$,
>   $u'' < 0$.

Comment: Nice problem. So what is the solution? Any hint?

Comment: are you working with finite or infinite horizon?

Comment: @RScrlli, i suppose infinite horizon

Comment: @RobertZ Z,I found this problem in the textbook  'Dynamic Optimization' Morton I. Kamien, Nancy L.Schwartz (chapter 'Equilibria in Infinite Horizon
Autonomous Problems'), maybe it will be useful. I tried to solve it in a similar way, but reasoning is at an impasse.

Comment: did you write the Hamiltonian ?

Comment: @RScrlli, if I did everything right, then H = u(c) + lambda (a N - b N^2 - c).

Comment: You should add the discount factor $e^{-rt}$

Comment: @RScrlli, Well, in this case we get that the optimal c is obtained for $$e^{-rt} u' = \lambda $$ (because $$H_{cc}^{''} < 0$$ and $$ H_{c}^{'} =  e^{-rt} u' - \lambda $$). My problem is that I do not understand what can be done next.

Comment: I think that the exercise is just asking you to characterise the solution, of course that without any parameters/functions you cannot solve the exercise

Answer (score 2):

Since the fish becomes cheaper at rate $r$, the Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal L=\int_0^\infty w(c(t))e^{-rt}dt
$$

The Hamiltonian here is:
$$
H(t, N, c,\lambda)=w(c)e^{-rt} +\lambda(a N-bN^2-c) %+\mu N
\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial c}=0=w'(c)e^{-rt}-\lambda\\
\lambda = w'(c) e^{-rt}\\
\dot \lambda =-\frac{\partial H}{\partial N}=-a\lambda+2b\lambda N\\
-rw'(c)e^{-rt}+w''(c)\dot c e^{-rt}=-e^{-rt}(a-2bN)\\[20pt]
w''(c)\dot c=r w'(c)+2bN-a\\
\dot N=aN-bN^2-c
$$

We have ODE with initial condition $N(0)=N_0$ and ending condition $\lambda(t_{end})=0$ ($t_{end}$ is the time when fish is depleted from the lake $N(t_{end})=0$).

There can be a case when the end condition cannot be satisfied and $\lambda(t_{end})>0$. That means the fish becomes cheaper faster than it can grow. So the optimal solution will be to fish all the fish as fast as you can $c=N_0\delta(t)$.